# Cannot find module '@angular/core' + ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic3

**angular/core** is actually in the right place.
This is the first time I am facing this issue. what to do in this case?

I have started to encounter issues with the integration of FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

this is my **package.json**

**added**  `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0",`
same error : *cannot copy this one is the ionic output*

[image]

so, I have downgraded

from :

```
 "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0"
```

to :

```
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3",
```

**AND,**

from :

```
"firebase": "^4.13.1",
```

to :

```
  "firebase": "^4.6.0",
```

======================================================

```
{
  "name": "authNotificationTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-plus": "git+https://github.com/guyromb/cordova-plugin-fcm-plus.git",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^4.13.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-fcm": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    }
  }
}
```

this is my **ionic info**:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v9.11.1
npm   : 5.6.0
OS    : macOS High Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

error log :

when I run **ionic cordova run browser**

```
 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
vendor.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

when I run **ionic serve**

and, this is from the console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
vendor.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
vendor.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: What is the exact error log?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the error logs when I run 'ionic cordova run browser' and 'ionic serve'. Thanks

Comment: looks like angularfire2 is throwing it.. which version? I dont see it in package.json

Comment: Also please paste error logs as text and not image

Comment: updated. I have came accross this discussion about incompatibility :https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1338. My project still won't run

Comment: I think what you are looking for is https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1385

Comment: fixed!as always super helpful suraj. Many thanks!!

Comment: You can add an answer and accept it to help others :)

Comment: yep. answer added and I will accept tmw as per site's rules. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Suraj Rao's comment, here is where you can find the solution to the issue :
*"FirebaseApp not implemented correctly"* like the screenshot below

[image]

Please refer to this thread for more details: :[github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1385](http://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1385)

Rolling back to `"firebase": "4.8.0"` helped to hereabove resolve the problem